# Can't ssh to GCE instance after mounting /home

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, google-compute-engine

After creating a new instance (+ attached disk in /dev/sdb) and sshing to it via browser, i'm running:

```
[root@instance-01 ~]# mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sdb
[root@instance-01 ~]# mkdir /media/disk
[root@instance-01 ~]# mount /dev/sdb /media/disk
[root@instance-01 ~]# cp -vrp /home/* /media/disk
[root@instance-01 ~]# umount /dev/sdb
[root@instance-01 ~]# echo "/dev/sdb  /home  ext4  defaults,noatime 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
[root@instance-01 ~]# mount -a
```

i thought i could logout and login again (browser SSH), since my credentials are inplace, but after logging out, i can't reconnect (timeout after the third try).

Then, i tried via gcloud tools (gcloud compute ssh "instance-01"):

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

My reasoning is: why SSH stopped working if the keys are the same (same place, ownership, mode and timeststamp, thanks to cp -p).

I even rebooted the VM, to no avail.